# If I enable migrations "July 2013 Breaking Changes" of my app, then search user by email wouldn't work

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the search graph API to search for users by email. Here's an example of how I do that:

```
GET  https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Sample%40gmail.com&fields=name%2clink%2ceducation%2cid%2cwork%2cabout%2cpicture&limit=2&type=user&access_token=...
```

Before the [July 2013 Breaking Changes](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/q3_2013_migration/) it was working fine. Once I enabled the breaking changes I start getting HTTP 403 saying that that the access token is not valid.

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "insufficient_scope" "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint"
X-FB-Rev: 798183
X-FB-Debug: lZPVbdTmZrCo+Bde/MNEXy/halUzQx7qIDW5aiZeT0g=
Date: Mon, 29 Apr 2013 07:25:29 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 120

{"error":{"message":"(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

Once I remove the %40 (@ sign) or the '.com' part from the request I get a normal HTTP 200 results. The problem is, that it's not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to search for users by email the way I was able before.

Example of requests that **does** work:

```
GET  https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Samplegmail.com&fields=name%2clink%2ceducation%2cid%2cwork%2cabout%2cpicture&limit=2&type=user&access_token=...
GET  https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Sample%40gmail&fields=name%2clink%2ceducation%2cid%2cwork%2cabout%2cpicture&limit=2&type=user&access_token=...
```

Comment: Are you using an app access token?

Comment: Are you sure "access_token==", instead of "access_token="? Or you want to edit your question?

Comment: I'm using an app access token. and the == was a typo in the question (I edited it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 林果皞 said. This is a bug in the graph API. I filed a bug here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/335452696581712

Answer (score 1):

have you try `FQL`?

> SELECT uid,username,first_name, middle_name, pic,pic_small, pic_big,
>   pic_square, 
>   last_name,name,email,birthday,birthday_date,contact_email,current_address,current_location,education,hometown_location,
>   languages, locale,profile_url,sex,work FROM user where
>   contains('youremail@example.com')

Answer (score 0):

Search by email works fine to me (Access token just granted basic permissions enough):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dlimkokhole%40gmail.com%26fields%3Dname%2Clink%2Ceducation%2Cid%2Cwork%2Cabout%2Cpicture%26limit%3D2%26type%3Duser

[image]

> **Update**:
>
> Recently Graph API explorer app already enabled "July 2013 Breaking
>   Changes". So the example i've shown above whouldn't work anymore.

Comment: I think that this test environment is without the July 2013 Breaking Changes. As I said, it's working fine without the breaking changes.

Comment: No, it's not related to test environment, even i using another application's user access token is no problem. For example, using your web browser request https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=limkokhole@gmail.com&fields=name,link,education,id,work,about,picture&limit=2&type=user&access_token= (PUT you user access token at the end)

Comment: Ok, i understand your problem. It should be a bug and kindly report it on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Actually the question can be simplified: If i enable migrations "July 2013 Breaking Changes" of my app, then search user by email wouldn't work. :)