# Facebook search be email fails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

I have a search to make based on the email that is publicly available.
The problem is that it gives

```
{"error": {
"message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 200
```

}
}

but with another older app .. i get the results

```
{"data": [
{
  "name": "<Privacy>", 
  "id": "<Privacy>"
}], "paging": {
"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=<email>&type=user&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=1131330642"
```

}
}

i used the following query both the times

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?type=user&q=<email>&Access_Token=<Token>
```

Comment: duplicated: We already have the conclusion from discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273644/if-i-enable-migrations-july-2013-breaking-changes-of-my-app-then-search-user/16275068#16275068

Comment: @林果皞 thanks a lot ... i added to your bug report .. hope that they work on it a little faster ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug for apps that enabled "July 2013 Breaking Changes" which describes this exact problem... I personally had this issue. Just disable "July 2013 breaking changes" in your app settings and hope that this will be fixed before July 10th when the breaking changes apply to all facebook apps.

Check out: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/335452696581712?browse=search_5187796ecdd086833270863

Comment: yup already filed a bug ... see the problem is with them ... the emails that have been made public to search by should give data if no permissions are given ... it should give no data ... not an OAUTH exception

Comment: there´s nothing to be fixed, it´s not a bug. it´s just not possible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search for Emails (anymore), you even need a specific additional permission to read the Email of your own user, Email is kind of private usually. The Search Type you are using is "user", so you can only search for user names.

Further information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

Comment: then how come it works if i use a different app ? @luschn i am really curious if facebook is trying to phase it out or something ?

Comment: why the downvote? what´s wrong with my answer? if it works in an older app, it might be that it worked earlier and the old app is not upgraded yet. happens sometimes, same goes for the deprecated offline_access permissions. in some older apps it still works as far as i have heard.
i mean, why would facebook allow anyone to search for email addresses? think about the privacy.